# iOS - Check [CGPoint] make a straight line

Tags: ios, swift, geometry, core-graphics

Assuming I have an array of `CGPoints`, how can I check if they produce a straight line?

For example, imagine a grid. Assuming I plotted all of the points on the grid, how can I check if all the points make either a straight horizontal, vertical or diagonal line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to compute the [Line of Best Fit](https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/least-squares-regression.html) for your points to determine if they lie on a line.

```
func pointsFormALine(_ points: [CGPoint]) -> Bool {

    // helper function to test if CGFloat is close enough to zero
    // to be considered zero
    func isZero(_ f: CGFloat) -> Bool {
        let epsilon: CGFloat = 0.00001

        return abs(f) < epsilon
    }

    // variables for computing linear regression
    var sumXX: CGFloat = 0  // sum of X^2
    var sumXY: CGFloat = 0  // sum of X * Y
    var sumX:  CGFloat = 0  // sum of X
    var sumY:  CGFloat = 0  // sum of Y

    for point in points {
        sumXX += point.x * point.x
        sumXY += point.x * point.y
        sumX  += point.x
        sumY  += point.y
    }

    // n is the number of points
    let n = CGFloat(points.count)

    // compute numerator and denominator of the slope
    let num = n * sumXY - sumX * sumY
    let den = n * sumXX - sumX * sumX

    // is the line vertical or horizontal?
    if isZero(num) || isZero(den) {
        return true
    }

    // calculate slope of line
    let m = num / den

    // calculate the y-intercept
    let b = (sumY - m * sumX) / n

    print("y = \(m)x + \(b)")

    // check fit by summing the squares of the errors
    var error: CGFloat = 0
    for point in points {
        // apply equation of line y = mx + b to compute predicted y
        let predictedY = m * point.x + b
        error += pow(predictedY - point.y, 2)
    }

    return isZero(error)
}
```

**Test:**

```
pointsFormALine([CGPoint(x: 1, y: 2), CGPoint(x: 2, y: 4), CGPoint(x: 5, y: 10)])  // true
pointsFormALine([CGPoint(x: 1, y: 2), CGPoint(x: 1, y: 4), CGPoint(x: 1, y: 10)])  // true
pointsFormALine([CGPoint(x: 1, y: 2), CGPoint(x: 2, y: 2), CGPoint(x: 5, y: 2)])   // true
pointsFormALine([CGPoint(x: 1, y: 2), CGPoint(x: 2, y: 1), CGPoint(x: 2, y: 2)])   // false
```

Comment: Thanks. This method works fine for horizontal and vertical lines, however, doesn't work for diagonal lines. Do you know how it could be changed to support diagonal lines?

Comment: I managed to get this working for diagonals by basically assuming the value is 0 if it's below 1. Not sure this is mathematically correct, but appears to work fine for my specific use case. Thank you. I'll mark as the answer for this.

Comment: Could you give an example of the `CGPoint` data points you are using?  The error is really `0` for a straight line.

Comment: Sure. Here are the diagonal points which are failing for me: [(211.75, 256.25), (163.25, 303.75), (115.25, 351.25)]. This gives us an error of 0.0403810359022123.

Comment: It doesn't matter. I made a foolish mistake when mapping the users finger location to my grid of cells. This meant the users finger has to be exactly center to get 0 (which is hard to do). Turns out your code works perfectly for diagonals too! Thank you :)